# Create a function to calculate mean of selected range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I try to create a user defined function in Excel. In order to get the average number of any selected range, let's say the range of cells of H2 to H10, I create the following function.

```
Function avg(rng As Range) As Single

  Dim i%, nrow%, col%
  Dim sum As Single

  nrow = rng.Rows.Count
  col = rng.Column
  sum = 0

  For i = 1 To nrow
      sum = sum + Cells(i, col).Value
  Next i

  avg = sum / nrow

End Function
```

However, when I enter the function in a cell and select the range of H1 to H10, the result gives a wrong average number. I don't even know how the number is calculated. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dim `sum` as `Double` instead of Single.  Also, use a `For Each` loop instead of a `For i = 1 to nrow`

Comment: I'm also assuming you're doing this as an exercise to practice VBA, because there's already a built in Excel function to calculate an average `=AVERAGE(H2:H10)`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using the built-in Excel function AVERAGE?

Comment: That's right @tigeravatar. I am practicing VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP is willing to become proficient in VBA it could be useful for him to see what was wrong in its original code

```
Function avg(rng As Range) As Single
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sum As Double

  For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through each single cell of passed range that contains a number
      sum = sum + cell.Value '<--| update sum
  Next
  avg = sum / rng.Count '<--| return average
End Function
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) for `SpecialCells()` method

Comment: @WeberChen, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in `col` initialization because the correct form is:

```
 col=rng.columns.count
```

This code works perfectly:

```
Option Base 1
Function avg(rng As Range) As Single

  Dim i%, nrow%, ncol%, j%
  Dim sum As Single

  nrow = rng.Rows.Count
  ncol = rng.Columns.Count
  sum = 0

  For i = 1 To nrow
   For j = 1 To ncol
      sum = sum + rng(i, j)
      Next j
  Next i
  avg = sum / (nrow * ncol)

End Function
```

Comment: Moreno, I really appreciate that your help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit advanced, but here's a more robust version for a VBA Average function, which I hope helps you learn VBA:

```
Public Function AverageVBA(ParamArray vValues() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim vSubValue As Variant
    Dim dSum As Double
    Dim lCount As Long

    dSum = 0
    lCount = 0

    For Each vValue In vValues
        If IsArray(vValue) Or TypeName(vValue) = "Collection" Or TypeName(vValue) = "Range" Then
            For Each vSubValue In vValue
                If IsNumeric(vSubValue) And Len(vSubValue) > 0 Then
                    lCount = lCount + 1
                    dSum = dSum + vSubValue
                End If
            Next vSubValue
        Else
            If IsNumeric(vValue) And Len(vValue) > 0 Then
                lCount = lCount + 1
                dSum = dSum + vValue
            End If
        End If
    Next vValue

    If lCount = 0 Then
        AverageVBA = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
    Else
        AverageVBA = dSum / lCount
    End If

End Function
```

**EDIT** After testing and updating the UDF, got it working exactly like the built in Average function

Comment: Thank you so much, Tigeravatar. I would enjoy learning from your code.